# How to convert java from clipboard (outside Android Studio) to kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

If I copy code from a java class (open in android studio) and paste it in a kotlin class. The code is automatically converted.

BUT, if I copy this code outside of Android studio (SOF, slack etc). The code is not converted.

My config:

[image]

Android studio 3.6 RC2 (I had the same problem in the lower versions)

I searched a similar plugin to the one for appcode (Swiftify) with a similar feature (but for kotlin - "Paste as Kotlin"). But I didn't find anything.

[image]

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is done when you paste the java code in android studio, not in the clipboard. If you want to pass a koltin transformed code you have to transforme it in android studio (paste it) and then copy-paste outside

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said in my post.
I'm just looking for a solution from the clipboard. Like on AppCode for swift

Comment: Ah ok, so I don't know